# HTML: password field is not getting cleared

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to clear an input type password field. I've tried with all the methods such as

1) **$('#password').val(' ');**

2) **setTimeout(function(){ $('#password').val(' ');}, 50);**

3) **$("input[type='password']").val(' ');**

4) **$scope.model.password = ' ';**

5) **document.getElementById('password').value = ' ';**

Among these only, the 5th one had cleared my password object, but even then the value was not cleared from the HTML page. 
Just wanted to know why is the Screen retaining the password, seems like a cache issue in HTML. But the thing is the model.userName gets cleared in HTML page and not the password field.

This is my **HTML code**

```
<div class="modal_sections">
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="text" ng-keydown="loginKeydown($event)" ng-model="model.userName"> </li>
    <li>
        <input type="password" ng-keydown="loginKeydown($event)" ng-model="model.password" placeholder="***********" id="password"> </li>
</ul>
```

And this is my **controller code**

```
   var resetPassword = function () {
        if (condition) {
            $('#password').val('');
            setTimeout(function () { $('#password').val(''); }, 50);
            $("input[type='password']").val('');
            $scope.model.password = '';
            document.getElementById("password").value = "";
            document.getElementById("password").placeholder = "";
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me out on this?  I just want to clear the password from HTML page as well.

Comment: have you tried with **ng-value=''**

Comment: yes I have tried just now. Unfortunately it dint work. The issue is internally in code, the password value is getting cleared, but the same is not getting cleared in the HTML page.

Comment: then you must need to clear the password field from where you are getting the data can u please upload your model binding code

Comment: please provide controller code.

Comment: Yes, Please check the code below 



 ` var resetPassword = function () {
            if (condition) {
                $('#password').val('');
                 setTimeout(function(){ $('#password').val('');}, 50);
                $("input[type='password']").val('');
                $scope.model.password = '';
                document.getElementById("password").value = "";
                document.getElementById("password").placeholder = "";
            }
        } `

Comment: what you get in password field? and this is not controller code are you using proper angular methods

Comment: I get the password that I've entered, and upon clearing it gets cleared as well, via the 5th point I've mentioned above.

Comment: then what is the question what exactly you want? value not cleared from html page that means where which html page?

Comment: ` <div class="modal_sections">
<ul>
<li><input type="text" ng-keydown="loginKeydown($event)"  ng-model="model.userName">
</li>
<li><input type="password" ng-keydown="loginKeydown($event)" ng-model="model.password" placeholder="***********" id="password">
</li>
</ul>
</div> ` 

See my issue is password field getting cleared in model object in the js file, but not on HTML screen while displaying. Am I clear now?  

Just wanted to know why is the Screen retaining the password, seems like a cache issue in HTML. 

But the funny thing is the model.userName gets cleared in HTML page.

Comment: If there wasn't any proper solution given then why was the question ranked a negative?

Comment: don't write code in comments please update your question

Answer (score 0):

You have added a space to the password field while resetting remove that. It will work perfectly.

```js
function clearPassword(){
document.getElementById('password').value = '';
}

function checkValue() {
var passwordFieldValue = document.getElementById('password').value;
alert("Value of password field= " + passwordFieldValue);
}
```

```html
<input type="password" ng-keydown="loginKeydown($event)" ng-model="model.password" class="form-control password" placeholder="*****" id="password" autocomplete="off">
<button onClick="clearPassword()">Clear</button>
<button onClick="checkValue()">Check Value</button>
```

Comment: please check for the proper problem he is using model binding in input field

Comment: Can I know why did I get that -1?

Comment: He mentioned that he is using this approach too. Can you see that 5th option?

Comment: and where is the model.password value?

Comment: Put some value in the password field and click on check value and clear that value and again click on check value. That's what he needs though.

Comment: @Harish Soni; Actually I have added a space here just for the sake of readability alone. Again this snippet of code just clears my password value in my JS file, and the alert shows " Value of password field=  " 
But still the password field in the HTML is not at all getting cleared. 

I don't know whats wrong in it.

Comment: Can you please post your angular controller code in your question so that I can see what is going wrong in that?
Do you need that placeholder also to be cleared?

Comment: Do you want to prevent from getting password with other credentials ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to clear the password field by clicking on some button then use

HTML:

```
<button ng-click = someFunction()>CLick Me </button>
```

JS:

```
someFunction(){
     $scope.model.password=null;
 }
```

Comment: This answer does not give more details. Please improve you answer . Give some explanation as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely clear the field then you have to clear the placeholder value as well. I am posting pure js code, if you want to accomplish it in different way you can easily do it. You get the idea

```
function change() {
    var x = document.getElementById("psw").value = "";
    var x = document.getElementById("psw").placeholder = "";
}
```

The running code sample is here https://jsfiddle.net/uj8yyp1d/

Comment: Even this did not clear the password value in HTML page

Answer (score 0):

Don't work with jQuery, using `ng-model` works fine. Make sure your `$scope.model` is defined. You can't reset some property if it's *undefined*.

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("test", function($scope){
 $scope.model={};
 $scope.model.userName = "abc";
 $scope.model.password = "123";
  
 $scope.resetPassword = function () {
  $scope.model.userName = "";
     $scope.model.password = "";
 }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">

<div ng-controller="test" class="modal_sections">
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="text" ng-model="model.userName"> 
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="password" ng-model="model.password" placeholder="***********" id="password"> 
    </li>
</ul>
<button type="button" ng-click="resetPassword()">Clear</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i tried this as well, but it dint work as long as the type is password for the input field. I'm posting the workaround I have done below.

Comment: it should work. Check for any use of asynchronous data, any typos, maybe the input field is out of scope of the controller. Stuff like that